# If $\mu (x,y) = e^{\int h(xy) d(xy) }$ then is $\mu$ a function of $xy$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If $\mu (x,y) = e^{\int h(xy) d(xy) }$ then is $\mu$ a function of $xy$?

We can say $\mu (x,y) = \mu(xy)$?

Comment: I assume $d(xy)$ meaning integrating over the product of two Lebesgue measures $\mu \times \mu$? If $h(xy)$ is only about $x, y$, then you should get a constant number.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is technically abuse of notation, since another way to write this would be $\mu(x,y)=(\phi\circ\mathop{\mathrm{mult}})(x,y)$ with $\mathop{\mathrm{mult}}$ being multiplication (so $\mathop{\mathrm{mult}}(x,y)=xy$) and $\phi$ being a function in a single-variable (namely $\phi(t)=e^{\int h(t)\text dt}$), and then renaming $\phi$ to $\mu$ again.

So while not totally technically correct, this last step is a common thing to do within the mathematical community.

Comment: And even more so within the physical community.

Answer (score 0):

If the integral is simple, yes.

Assume $H$ to be an antiderivative of $h$, then

$$\mu(x,y)=\nu(xy)=e^{H(xy)}.$$

This works by considering $xy$ as an independent variable.